# What is the meaning of the "§" symbol (on the upper left corner of the mac keyboard)?

Tags: keyboard

The title says it all, but I'll repeat it here:

What is the meaning of the "§" symbol (on the upper left corner of the mac keyboard) as highlighted  in the image here?

Apparently, this is not printed on mac keyboards sold in the US, though it is on models sold in Europe (or Israel, in my case).

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign

Comment: @Lizzan , shall put this as the answer or would you like to?

Comment: Go for it, I don't have the time to write a full answer right now. :)

Comment: On the standard US keyboard, this character is at Option - 6

Comment: It's also the Simleons sign ;P

Comment: @rolin It's similar to, but not the same as the simoleon symbol.  Notably, the simoleon's graphic design has a normal circle at the center, not a pair of conjoined curves.

Comment: does anyone know how to change this key to write "back quote" (`) programmatically?

Comment: Notably, this and any other unknown symbol can be searched on DuckDuckGo. This immediately revealed the name of the symbol: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%C2%A7&ia=web

Comment: for me ~ and ' symbol are present, when typing § and ± are showing how to correct it?

Comment: @kiran Switch the layout on your computer to match the one on your keyboard. You might have a US English keyboard, so you could try that.

Comment: @Liggliluff I switch to US English keyboard! still same result!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"§" is the section sign, as answered by [@Lizzan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176968/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-symbol-on-the-upper-left-corner-of-the-mac-keybo#comment209153_176968).

Excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign):

> The section sign (§) is a [typographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography) character used mainly to refer to a particular [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_%28typography%29) of a document, such as a [legal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_%28law%29). It is also called "double S" and "sectional symbol".
>   It is also sometimes used to link to a [footnote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_%28typography%29) where the [asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) (*) is already in use on a given page.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [Section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign), and is used in Minecraft for color formatting codes.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, it is the “section sign” symbol. I had no idea it was on some keyboards! On my American Apple keyboard, I can type it as ⌥6 (Option-6).